# Google Wave Python Tutorial - Nothing happens

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-wave

For the [Google Wave Python Robot Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/python-tutorial.html), my capabilities.xml is visible and I can add it to a Wave, but the robot isn't actually responding to the events. I checked the logs, but I've fixed it so I'm not getting any more errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's known issue with Wave API: [Issue 158](http://code.google.com/p/google-wave-resources/issues/detail?id=158) Fix is ready and is expected to be deployed in "coming days".

Comment: According to the issue tracker, this is now fixed